# PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '['

Tags: php, joomla

I got few lines producing error 500. The error log says:

> PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '[' in...

and the lines are:

```
 $catids[] = $params->get('catid');
```

and after commenting it out, this one comes up:

```
$return_category[] = self::_getCategoryInfor($tg, $params)[0];
```

How can i modify them in order to match with new PHP versions and solve the error 500?

Comment: That can depend on alot of stuff. Are both variables arrays?

Comment: Check the preceding line and make sure it ends with a semicolon?

Comment: @BradzTech “unexpected [”, not «unespected $...»

Answer (score 0):

From your code, I do not see code that may triggered this parse error. Try change your code so it becomes:

```
$categories = self::_getCategoryInfor($tg, $params);
$return_category[] = $categories[0];
```

Comment: Works great for me!
Thanks a lot Zamrony

Answer (score 0):

This is the expression causing the error:

```
self::_getCategoryInfor($tg, $params)[0];
```

Function array dereferencing was added in PHP 5.4. Your code will generate a parse error on 5.3 or lower:

https://secure.php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php